# SharePoint mapped as network drive no longer works

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, network-drive

I have in the past accessed two SharePoint sites on our company network by mapping them as network drives. That is, I have added a network drive in File Explorer to a URL of the form

```
https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/1234
```

I work mostly via VPN, so on login the drives show as disconnected. Upon opening the drive for the first time per session, the connection would get established and I was able to browse the site contents.

This has worked until recently, when I started getting an error message when I tried to access the drive (by double-clicking the disconnected drive in Explorer). The message reads:

```
An error occurred while reconnecting S: to
https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/1234
Web Client Network: The network path was not found.

This connection has not been restored.
```

I have tried removing and re-mapping one of the two drives, which fails with the message:

```
Error code: 0x80070043
The network name cannot be found.
```

I can still open the URL in my web browser (indicating the site is available and name resolution works).

OS is Windows 7. The Web Client service is running (started manually). I have added the SharePoint site to the Trusted Sites zone in Internet Explorer.

What gives?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I’d say this is a generic question: What settings need to be in place on the client and the SharePoint server in order for drive mapping to work, and what change to a once working setup would cause the aforementioned malfunction?

Comment: For the record, I was finally able to map the site as `\\sharepoint.mycompany.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\1234` (note the extra `DavWWWRoot` in the path).

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm, this trick don't seems to work anymore since the last 2years..

Microsoft probably made some changes to prevent this type of "mapped drive sync" as they are rather working to get their priority "ms teams" and "onerive" syncs to work correctly.

Two method with a lot of synchronization problem when used as it proposes it is as a collaborative enterprise tool with a lot of use + file through ms teams. Also another point aside, I wanted to adress that the main goal of microsoft is to minimise admin intervention by allowing people to manage their own team and files rights are completely lacking. The rights in teams are so badly designed and do not allow the user to properly split the rights in the same channel on subdirectories .... They must create private channels and add people then on the side of the person invited she must manually display the channel .... bravo.

Example, if you paid attention, in teams you can apply the right to "modify" or "read" when you are invited in a channel and so how do you want people to understand that for advanced rights they have to go in sharepoint ......

My overal score about this project (teams/sharepoint/onedrive) for them is 3/10.

I imagine that they put young new interns fresh out of school to participate in this major project.